# How can I change the Jersey created error messages?

Tags: java, http, jersey

I have a Jersey app that has been run through our corporations website vulnerability tool. It came back with a vulnerability that is quite odd. If you send in this header:

```
"*/*'"!@$^*\/:;.,?{}[]`~-_<sCrIpT>alert(81363)</sCrIpT>"
```

You get an error message back in the BODY from jersey:

```
The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "*/*'"!@$^*\/:;.,?{}[]`~-_<sCrIpT>alert(56224)</sCrIpT>" could not be parsed.
```

This is not acceptable to our Security Team.  It does come back as "text/plain" which is correct and all, but I need to change the message.  Any way to do this?

This is running on Tomcat and I am using Jersey 1.14.

Comment: Are you able to perform any success- or exception-checking when the Jersey resource returns?

Comment: No.  It doesn't even hit my code.  Jersey tries to match the accept header to what I have set up and fails, AND they can't even parse the thing.  So I don't see anything in my code.  That is what makes this different than other posts on Stackoverflow...

Comment: which app server is it running out of?

Comment: in addition to @foampile's request, please mention the jersey version as well.

Comment: Are you using Apache as your web server?  If this error message is associated with a unique URL you can specify a redirect rule in httpd.conf.  I don't know how it would be done if you are using only Tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Pavel on the Jersey team:

You should be able to purge the entity from your servlet filter, or you can register ContainerResponseFilter in Jersey, something like:

```
public class PurgeErrorEntityResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        if(response.getStatus() == 400) {
            response.setEntity(null);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

and web.xml:

```
 <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
       <param-value>x.y.z.PurgeErrorEntityResponseFilter</param-value>
   </init-param>
```

This worked for me.  I did this:

```
response.setEntity(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(response.getEntity().toString()));
```

and it escaped the error message.  Thanks Pavel!